# CakePHP complex find conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-1.2

For example I have a Store model with fields fromH and toH, I want to retrieve stores from database that are open in given hour (@t).

SQL query would look like this

```
select *
from store 
where 
( fromH < toH and @t between fromH and toH ) or
( fromH > toH and 
     (@t between fromH and 24 OR
     (@t between 1 and toH )
)
```

How do I implement this query in cakephp, how would the conditions array look? I want to do it cake style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given by @Arun Jain is very close to the solution but as the rules for the OR states must each be their own array, because their key values are identical. If you

```
print_r($conditions);
```

you'll find some of your rules are missing.

I think following solution will work for you.

```
$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            array(
                'AND' => array(
                    'fromH <' => 'toH',
                    @t.' BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('fromH','toH')
                 )
            ),
            array(
                'AND' => array(
                    'fromH >' => 'toH',
                    'OR' => array(
                        @t.' BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('fromH','24'),
                        @t.' BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('1','toH')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$this->Strore->find('all',$conditions);
```

Comment: When I try to run this query I get following error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '15' in 'where clause' - "15" is @t

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with the following CakePHP equivalent select query:

```
<?php $this->Store->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'AND' => array(
                'fromH < ' => 'toH',
                $t.' BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('fromH', 'toH')
            )
        ),
    'AND' => array(
            'fromH > ' => 'toH',
            'OR' => array(
                $t.' BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('fromH', '24'),
                $t.' BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('1', 'toH')
            )
        ),
    )
));
```

Comment: May want to fix the double between, too.